# Python MFC: Updating static text in response to events

Tags: python, mfc

I have the following Python MFC code.  I have a listbox which I fill with some values, and when the user clicks on the values I want the static text control to be updated with the current selection.  There are two problems with this code.  The first is that the value in the text control is only updated the first time I click on the listbox.  The second is that the value lags behind the real selected value in the listbox, presumably because the control handles the click after my handler code gets called.  I'd appreciate help with either of these issues.

An odd thing, (perhaps a clue) is that when I mouse-down over the 'OK' button but move away for mouse-up the static text does get updated as I would expect.

I've tried RedrawWindow(), UpdateWindow(), ShowWindow() on both the control and the dialog, and nothing seems to make any difference.

```
import win32con
from pywin.mfc import dialog

IDC_LIST = 9000
IDC_TEXT = 9001

class ChooserDialog(dialog.Dialog):

  def __init__(self):
    DIALOGTEMPLATE = [  
      ["Test", (0, 0, 254, 199), win32con.WS_CAPTION | win32con.DS_MODALFRAME, None, (8, "MS SansSerif")],
      [128, "OK", win32con.IDOK, (197,178,50,14), win32con.BS_PUSHBUTTON | win32con.WS_VISIBLE],
      ["listbox", "List", IDC_LIST, (7,7,177,186), win32con.WS_VISIBLE],
      ["static", "", IDC_TEXT, (197,7,50,160), win32con.WS_CHILD | win32con.WS_VISIBLE]
    ]
    dialog.Dialog.__init__(self, DIALOGTEMPLATE)

  def OnInitDialog(self):
    rc = dialog.Dialog.OnInitDialog(self)
    for i in ["one", "two", "three"]:
      self.GetDlgItem(IDC_LIST).AddString(i)
    self.HookCommand(self.OnNotify, IDC_LIST)
    return rc

  def OnNotify(self, ctrl, action):
    if ctrl == IDC_LIST:
      selected = self.GetDlgItem(IDC_LIST).GetCurSel()
      self.SetDlgItemText(IDC_TEXT, "%d" % selected)
      self.GetDlgItem(IDC_TEXT).RedrawWindow()
    return 1

dia = ChooserDialog()
dia.DoModal()
```

Comment: `RedrawWindow` should have done it, could you add that to your example code?

Comment: @Mark: should that be on the dialog or the control?

Comment: On the control itself.  Static controls, because they're "static" and don't change, don't repaint themselves automatically but have to be told.

Comment: OK. That's interesting. My first version used a 2nd list box instead of the static text and that had the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem with the code was that the win32con.LBS_NOTIFY style wasn't set for the listbox control.  If that isn't set you won't get any messages from the LB.  The few messages that I was getting were due to other events in the dialog.

The second problem was that I was using HookCommand(), which intercepts commands, and allows you to handle them.  Instead I wanted HookMessage() to get only the notifications.  It seems notifications get called after the update of the control, so that's exactly what I wanted.

The LBN_SELCHANGE notification, according to MSDN documentation is received through the WM_COMMAND message.  It seems I must subscribe to all WM_COMMAND messages in the dialog, and then filter them in my handler.  The LBN_SELCHANGE documentation explains about what is passed, and in conjunction with the HookMessage() Python documentation you can work out how to handle it.

Here is the working code:

```
    import win32con
    from pywin.mfc import dialog

    IDC_LIST = 9500
    IDC_TEXT = 9501

    class ChooserDialog(dialog.Dialog):

      def __init__(self):
        DIALOGTEMPLATE = [  
          ["Test", (0, 0, 254, 199), win32con.WS_CAPTION | win32con.DS_MODALFRAME, None, (8, "MS SansSerif")],
          [128, "OK", win32con.IDOK, (197,178,50,14), win32con.BS_PUSHBUTTON | win32con.WS_VISIBLE],
          ["listbox", "List", IDC_LIST, (7,7,177,186), win32con.WS_VISIBLE|win32con.LBS_NOTIFY],
          ["static", "", IDC_TEXT, (197,7,50,160), win32con.WS_CHILD | win32con.WS_VISIBLE]
        ]
        dialog.Dialog.__init__(self, DIALOGTEMPLATE)

      def OnInitDialog(self):
        rc = dialog.Dialog.OnInitDialog(self)
        for i in ["one", "two", "three"]:
          self.GetDlgItem(IDC_LIST).AddString(i)
        self.HookMessage(self.OnNotifyCommand, win32con.WM_COMMAND)
        return rc

      def OnNotifyCommand(self, data):
        msg_id = data[1]   # should always be WM_COMMAND
        wParam = data[2]
        lParam = data[3]
        list_id = wParam & 0xffff
        notification_code = (wParam & 0xffff0000) >> 16
        if list_id != IDC_LIST: return    # not our list box.
        if notification_code != win32con.LBN_SELCHANGE: return    # Not a change of selection
        selected = self.GetDlgItem(IDC_LIST).GetCurSel()
        self.SetDlgItemText(IDC_TEXT, "%d"%selected)

    dia = ChooserDialog()
    dia.DoModal()
```